# How to use this API "xTaskCreate" to create multiple tasks?

Tags: freertos

I have read in link, This xTaskCreate  FreeRTOS API is used to create a task. Using this API we can create more number of tasks:

```
/* Task to be created. */


/* Task to be created. */
void vTaskCode( void * pvParameters )
{
    /* The parameter value is expected to be 1 as 1 is passed in the
    pvParameters value in the call to xTaskCreate() below. 
    configASSERT( ( ( uint32_t ) pvParameters ) == 1 );

    for( ;; )
    {
        /* Task code goes here. */
    }
}
```

I have seen this program example. I want to create two tasks. First task `blink led1`, second task `blink led2`.

I don't understand how to write program for two tasks.

Comment: Have a look at the one of the demo's on the FreeRTOS website. They create many tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to create the second task just call `xTaskCreate` twice, like below:

```
void vTaskLedGreen( void * pvParameters )
{
    /* The parameter value is expected to be 1 as 1 is passed in the
    pvParameters value in the call to xTaskCreate() below. 
    configASSERT( ( ( uint32_t ) pvParameters ) == 1 );

    for( ;; )
    {
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        GreenLedOff();
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        GreenLedOn();
    }
}

void vTaskLedRed( void * pvParameters )
{
    /* The parameter value is expected to be 1 as 1 is passed in the
    pvParameters value in the call to xTaskCreate() below. 
    configASSERT( ( ( uint32_t ) pvParameters ) == 1 );

    for( ;; )
    {
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        RedLedOff();
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        RedLedOn();
    }
}

/* Function that creates a task. */
void main( void )
{
BaseType_t xReturned;
TaskHandle_t xHandle = NULL;

    xReturned = xTaskCreate(
                    vTaskLedRed,       /* Function that implements the task. */
                    "RedLed",          /* Text name for the task. */
                    STACK_SIZE,      /* Stack size in words, not bytes. */
                    ( void * ) 1,    /* Parameter passed into the task. */
                    tskIDLE_PRIORITY,/* Priority at which the task is created. */
                    &xHandle );      /* Used to pass out the created task's handle. */

    if( xReturned != pdPASS )
    {
         ErrorHandler();
    }

    xReturned = xTaskCreate(
                    vTaskLedGreen,       /* Function that implements the task. */
                    "GreenLed",          /* Text name for the task. */
                    STACK_SIZE,      /* Stack size in words, not bytes. */
                    ( void * ) 1,    /* Parameter passed into the task. */
                    tskIDLE_PRIORITY,/* Priority at which the task is created. */
                    &xHandle );      /* Used to pass out the created task's handle. */

    if( xReturned != pdPASS )
    {
         ErrorHandler();
    }

    // Start the real time scheduler.
    vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```